# Install Citrix Online Plug-in on ubuntu

Tags: wine, citrix

I need your support as i'm trying to install Citrix Online Plug-in on Ubuntu which is different from Citrix Receiver but I've failed with all my trials so far.

The below link is for the official .exe source, and i can't find any debian extension or any other ubuntu compatible extension for the Online Plug-in software, I've tried to use Wine application but it gave me errors

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/legacy-client-software/online-plug-in-123.html

so is there any other alternative software that could do the same functions or is there any way i could install this program.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The link to download the Citrix Online Plug-in is at the bottom of the answer.

Quoted from Citrix:

> The Citrix online plug-in is the new name for server-side
>   virtualization. When users connect to published applications, they use
>   the online plug-in software, which is the plug-in for server-side
>   virtualization. The plug-in software is available for a range of
>   different devices so users can connect to published applications from
>   various platforms. **You can deploy and update the online plug-in
>   using Citrix Receiver.**

Here is the link for the [Receiver](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-130.html).

You may want to look at [Citrix Xen App Plugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixXenAppPlugin).  Here is the link for the [Citrix Online Plug-in for Linux (x86 client) v.11](http://ubuntuone.com/2t5VbfEzTZWN8b5yY4CkVm)